# Zammad SAML - OneLogin::RubySaml::ValidationError, Fingerprint mismatch

Tags: ruby, saml, onelogin, zammad

I am trying to configure SAML authentication for [Zammad](https://zammad.org) and I keep getting this fingerprint mismatch which does not make sense. I had compute the fingerprint using OpenSSL, both SHA1 and SHA256
and I'm still getting the fingerprint mismatch. I tried generated different certificates using SHA1 and SHA256 and computing respective fingerprints, still fingerprint error:

```
I, [2022-09-22T19:28:22.868683 #57117-109180]  INFO -- : (saml) Callback phase initiated.
E, [2022-09-22T19:28:22.876176 #57117-109180] ERROR -- : (saml) Authentication failure! invalid_ticket: OneLogin::RubySaml::ValidationError, Fingerprint mismatch
```

Any idea what might be the problem? Can I turn on debug to see how the fingerprint is computed?
I'm not Ruby savvy, so am not sure which knobs to turn.